# How to simplify such structures to calculate equivalent capacitance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, potential, capacitance

I am self studying electrostatics for competetive examinations but there is this series of questions demanding equivalent capacitance and I direly need a intuitive understanding of these situations.
[image][image][image]

Answer (score -1):

what you need to do is break the arrangement into simpler circuit.Like for the first image attach a battery between A and Be like a conventional circuit diagram.The two plates in the middle have no capacitance linked as they are on the same potential so the distance given is only to confuse students. basically it will transform a series connection of two capacitors.----|d|----|3d|----,well Im pretty sure you wont completely get it as it is difficult to explain it over here I suggest looking at some videos on youtube.